# accessing AD user through HttpContext using .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, active-directory, httpcontext, asp.net-core-2.2

I have searched for a solution online but to no avail - I am trying to access logged-in AD user through HttpContext in .NET Core 2.2 for an intranet application...

I saw a similar problem (link below)and have implemented their solution but my context is still null:-
[Link to similar problem](https://forums.asp.net/t/2152154.aspx?Configure%20Active%20Directory%20group%20and%20Check%20if%20user%20belongs%20to%20that%20AD%20group%20in%20Net%20CORE%202%202)

appsettings.json

[image: <code>appsettings</code>]

StartUp.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(HttpSysDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
        });

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("ADGroup", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new UserHelper.CheckADGroupRequirement(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ADGroup"])));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserHelper.CheckADGroupHandler>();
    }
```

I have implemented the CheckADGroupHandler in the same way as the solution in the link

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Screenshot showing context with null value:-

[image]

HomeController.cs

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ADGroup")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I am missing something but can't figure out what - any pointers appreciated...

Comment: `wi` has no value assigned until you step thru the statement. Did you check what do you get in `context.User.Identity`?

Comment: Have you attached the Authorize attribute over controller with Policy name as `ADGroup`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya amended screenshots

Comment: `wi` has value in it. What's the issue here(

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya it doesn't have my name - it should have my ADUser name

Comment: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Security.Claims/ClaimsIdentity/GetUserName/php-claimsidentity-getusername-method-examples.html

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - not sure how that will get logged on user into my Context?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for Windows Authentication with HTTP.sys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#httpsys), you're missing the call to `UseHttpSys()` in your Program.cs:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseHttpSys(options =>
        {
            options.Authentication.Schemes = 
                AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | 
                AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
            options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
        })
        .Build();
```

Windows Authentication is much easier to implement if you're running your app behind IIS, but if you're using HTTP.sys because you cannot use IIS, then it's worth noting that if you're able to upgrade to ASP.NET 3.0, you can now [use Windows Authentication with Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue within IIS Express...combined with upgrading Framework to 
.NET Core 3.0